# Fact about cofactors of matrices...

Tags: matrices

I was recently told that the cofactors of a matrix multiplied by certain entries of the matrix sum to 0 (or something along those lines...)

Until Google adds a feature to search for mathematical relationships based on keywords, I'm stuck trying to find out what this was. It's driving me insane but I really can't remember, does anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Perhaps you mean [Laplace expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) for a matrix with determinant zero?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it was similar to that but I think they were linked up like ${b_{i1}}{C_{j1}}$ rather than ${b_{i1}}{C_{i1}}$. I think if you sum all of those, it equals 0 or something like that...

Comment: Perhaps then you mean this: $\mathbf {A} \,\mathrm {adj} (\mathbf {A} )=\det(\mathbf {A} )\,\mathbf {I}$, which is essentially Cramer's rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix.

Comment: I don't think so but it seems related. I think it was something like:
${b_{i1}}{C_{j1}} + {b_{i2}}{C_{j2}} + ... + {b_{in}}{C_{jn}} = 0$ but it may only be up to (n-1) or it may not equal 0 but it was something like that...

(and I think it only worked for square matrices or it wouldn't work for square matrices or something....)